# ¿De dónde viene el acento de Maluma? ¿Es sólo paisa o hay algo más?

Tags: colombia

Dicen que Maluma habla con acento paisa bien marcado. Según varios artículos que he leído acerca de este acento, el "s" o "c" algunas veces se pronuncia con un sonido poco "z". Pero lo que se me nota cuando habla Maluma es que el "s"/"c" se pronuncia... con un sonido de "zh" o "sh" (lo siento no sé como deletrear con la IPA)... me parece un poco portugués o argentino.

En el video por su canción Vente Pa' Ca con Ricky Martin, en 0:18, se nota fuertemente cuando dice "voy pa' la piscina" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOe6dI2JhgU&ab_channel=RickyMartinVEVO

Expertos coinciden que Colombia es el país donde existe la mayor diversidad de acentos españoles... tal vez tiene un acento más específica que sólo paisa?

Comment: "voy pa" " es oye en varios lugares.

Comment: @Lambie no pregunté por el "voy pa'...." sino por "piscina"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque parece que es un tema fácil lo cierto es que es bastante delicado, por la gran variedad que existe en la pronunciación y la dificultad que lleva no solo explicarlo, sino que sea posible entenderlo.

Por otro lado la vida de Maluma ha dado tantos giros en tan poco tiempo que  la mezcla de acentos que utiliza en sus conversaciones y entrevistas es notorio.

En general hay que diferenciar, después de realizar el estudio, que el acento "Paisa", donde podemos encontrar ese tipo de "S" y la "S" que Maluma pronuncia en ocasiones y a la que aquí nos referimos, en una fonología afectada.

La pronunciación normal Paisa que se hace de ese mismo tipo de "S", no resulta tan exagerada. Esto se puede observar en el mismo acento cuando se escucha a la madre expresándose, la misma hermana de Maluma u otras personas cercanas a su entorno. En estos casos, si se presta atención, la "S" pronunciada es la misma, pero más suavizada.

Salvando las diferencias, y haciendo una comparativa que tiene cierto sentido; es como la "S" ",fricativa postalveolar sorda [ʃ] (sonido sh), que pronuncia el ex-presidente del gobierno de España Mariano Rajoy, y que existe en Gallego, pero pronunciada habitualmente de forma más suave y natural. El mismo sonido también existe en otras lenguas del norte de España y que sin embargo Rajoy al pronunciar lleva la "S" hacia el extremo la manera que tiene de articularla y que se asemeja más bien a un sonido Portugués. De esta manera, aún teniendo que ver con el acento "Gallego" su vocalización resulta afectada ó poco natural.

En este sentido, es normal que al escucharlo, como más arriba te refieres, digas que *te parezca un poco como el Portugués o Argentino*, pero es por ese motivo, pronuncia la "S" de manera inmoderada o que excede.

En el alfabeto Español la [S] se representan con las grafías S y s, y hay muchas variantes del (seseo) que no son fáciles de analizar, incluso dentro de estos hay un lugar para sonidos como la /θ/ ("z" española).

---

He puesto varios videos y al final intentare concretar que variante de seseo es, teniendo por delante que su pronunciación de inicio es afectada, parecida a Rajoy, en cuanto exceso, y salvando obviamente las diferencias. Ruego disculpas por si no lo expreso bien ó existen mal entendidos, no es mi intención.

**Cuestiones Varias:**

- Empezare por el tema del video. "*En el video por su canción Vente Pa' Ca con Ricky Martin, en 0:18, se nota fuerte cuando dice "voy para la piscina*"

En este video del 2016 entiendo que dice "voy para la pisçina", creo que  aunque se intuye el sonido que quieres decir, no lo aprecio tan claro como en otros sitios.

En este caso,  la palabra  "PISCINA" se convierte en "PISSINA" ó si me apuras intenta una "Ç",  *"Ç" C celdilla que llamamos*, "PISÇINA", pero no con un resultado general que complete el sonido que tu buscas ó al menos no lo percibo tan fuertemente. Aquí  "piscina" suena con una extraña "S larga o doble" derivada de la unión de la primera "S" de "PIScina" con la "C" posterior, convertida en Ç ó S, pero al alargarse tanto pierde su origen si lo tuviera, "PISSINA", por lo que no puedo apreciarlo suficientemente. Sin embargo, he buscado otro video en que sale su hermana y un amigo pronunciando la palabra "pisina" para ver la diferencia. El mismo sonido se puede encontrar en otros lugares de Iberoamérica ó incluso ese alargamiento en la España del Sur, cuando dicen "pishaa" sin dejar completamente limpio el sonido [ʃ], sh que es que intento encontrar.

---

- **Otra cuestión**;
- Dicen que Maluma habla con acento paisa bien marcado.

Aunque Maluma nació y reside aún en Colombia, su consideración como figura internacional lo ha situado en tantos escenarios que su acento inicial ya no es el que era.

- Para muestra un botón;

Aquí tienes una muestra en el Diario de Diana/Maluma, cuando Maluma tenía 16 años. En este sentido, es el mejor Maluma que he encontrado con acento paisa y en este caso el acento paisa si esta marcado, nada que ver con el acento que hoy tiene Maluma. El tiempo borro el rastro de aquel otro encanto.

Aquí podrás escuchar en varias ocasiones distintos tipos de "s", en el 0'40, ya hay una "s que te puede interesar, al 1'00 min., 2'03 min. etc...cuando pronuncia dos veces su edad "dieciséis años" 2'51 min. es también interesante, pero ese sonido de "[ʃ]" tan marcado, tampoco es propio, excede, lo normal sería pronunciarlo más suave, como se ve en otros videos.

Este video,, si no lo has visto, creo que en general te gustará. Al final del corte es gracioso por que una de las presentadores 4'39 min. cuando dice "Gracias", dice Glasias" ó algo así.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHG-sk3RbSs

*En el Diario de Diana/ Maluma*

---

Sin irnos muy lejos aquí hay otro video en que Maluma, aunque ya se nota que intenta controlar mejor el habla, pues va tomando conciencia de que delante se encuentran las cámaras, todavía es fácil apreciar los rasgos de esa "s" a la que te refieres, aunque como digo no todo el mundo paisa pronuncia esa "[ʃ]", con esa afectación de corte tan pronunciado.

El video en términos de acento, no tiene desperdicio, ya que intenta pronunciar mejor, pero con el mismo acento por lo que el sonido es mucho más claro. Sin embargo, aunque el acento es más claro la marcación de las demás palabras que vimos en el video inicial, han pasado a un segundo lugar, y a la vez si te das cuenta, ya se van introduciendo otras formalidades lingüísticas.

Desde que abre la puerta, "Gra[ʃ]ias a u[ʃ]tedes, por estar aquí con no[ʃ]otros ...cuando dice cocina..., son 3'24 min. "estupendos".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mehaW2UJdjY

*Maluma muestra su casa*

---

Este es un video de una entrevista en Nueva York, que combina varios acentos, ya hay más variedad que mezcla con otros rastros de los que hay que estar pendientes, aunque también aparecen y se escapan. Se nota, siempre eso si, que intenta corregir y mantener los acentos bajo control, ya se aprecia que es un Maluma más experimentado ante las cámaras. Fíjate en las "S", que tiene el acento del entrevistador que son constante, sin embargo en Maluma, cambia y utiliza muchas tipos distintos "S", incluso introduce algunas típicas Españolas". Aquel acento marcado del principio se muestra latente pero no es ya tan evidente.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ynm5t84iXo

*Entrevista a Maluma con En Diálogo con Longobardi (CNN en Español) / Completa (29/08/2021)*

---

Aquí puedes ver como otras personas de su entorno pronuncian la palabra "piscina"

- **VOY PARA LA PISCINA**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITV-ug8tAvg

La hermana de Maluma nos contó la verdad sobre el cantante | Suelta La Sopa | Entretenimiento

---

- **EL Sonido [ʃ] y su mezcla con la [S] estándar. Análisis**

Maluma actualmente intenta en general adaptar su lenguaje y pronunciación según los lugares o países que visita, EEUU, Perú, México, España (encontraras formas distintas de pronunciar, digamos que es una forma de agradar a su público)... aún así, los rasgos típicos de la "S" que buscamos, [ʃ] con sonido "sh", podemos encontrarla en el Español, en Andalucía solo en algunas partes, en Castilla, en lenguas del Norte de España, igual que en departamento de Antioquia en Colombia.

Ese sonido [ʃ] que Maluma pronuncia **se encuentra entre un sonido** sibilante alveolar sordo, es decir la **[s]** estándar, un sonido como un silbido suave pronunciado con la punta de la lengua en los alveolos, (alveolo donde se insertan los dientes) y un sonido fricativo postalveolar sordo **[ʃ]** con sonido **"sh"**, es decir, el aire pasa entre los órganos que intervienen en la pronunciación en la región postalveolar con la lengua próxima a la parte posterior, un poquito más atrás en la boca pero sin llegar al paladar duro. Ese sonido "S" estaría entre la **[s]** "s" y **[ʃ]** "sh".

Así pues, más concretamente y dicho lo mismo pero de otra forma, encontraríamos ese sonido "S" dentro de las Fricativas Alveolar Sorda [S], en aquellas que tienen un sonido de silencio débil, como son la sibilante alveolar retraída sorda [s̠], y la subforma apicoalveolar [s̺] , que recuerda a las *fricativas* (pasan rozando el aire) *retroflejas* (que se articulan en la región postalveolar ó postpalatal). Entre un sonido (s [s] y [ʃ] sh).

---

P.D Si aún quieres convertirte en fan nº 1 de este tipo de cosas y quieres profundizar en las variedades fonéticas que Maluma utiliza en sus canciones, puedes descárgate una tesis realizada en 2019/2020;

"**La variedad Colombiana en la letras de Maluma**"

**Univerdit`degli Studi di Padova**

Dipartimento di Studi Linguistici e Letterai de Jessica Santa Disfano. Relatrice: Prof.sa Maria Begona, Arbulu Barturen. Anno Accademico 2019/2020.

Se encuentra en Español, pero el tema que aquí hemos tratado, no lo he visto ó si aparece no lo encontrado, quizás por ser algo más especifico. En general hace referencia a la variedad caribeña, andina y otros rasgos típicos de Colombia y a las pronunciaciones y rasgos fonéticos y morfosintácticos. Esta interesante.

https://thesis.unipd.it/bitstream/20.500.12608/23402/1/Distefano_Jessica_2021.pdf

Espero en general que te haya servido y disfrutes con la tesis.

**Como conclusión** terminaría diciendo que el sonido utilizado por Maluma en esas "S" que escuchas, estaría situado entre la **[s]** "s" y **[ʃ]** "sh". Esa pronunciación excede a la forma habitual y por tanto, aunque el sonido **[ʃ]** , si se encuentra dentro del campo de sonidos sibilantes que entran dentro del campo fonológico Paisa, sin embargo, no lo utilizan de la forma que lo hace Maluma, con esa afección que excede su natural pronunciación, que es de forma natural, mucho más suave. Por ello, como apunte más arriba, no es de extrañar que según que oídos, ese parte parezca una palabra con acento o influencia Portuguesa ó Argentina. En cualquier caso, no creo que existan otros aspectos, más allá, de estos particularismos de índole personal.

Comment: guau pero que explicación exhaustiva! muchísimas gracias por haber escrito todo esto y haber buscado los video clips y ejemplos... me imagino que no fue tan fácil buscar ejemplos de su hermana y sus amigos diciendo la misma palabra a menos que seas un súper fan! he preguntado esta misma duda a muchos de mis amigos colombianos (incluso de algunos paisas) y nadie me tuvo una respuesta clara (de hecho... algunos no percibieron nada distinto en la "s"!). se la voy a enseñar su contesta a ellos

Answer (score 1):

Nació y se crió en Medellín, que es la capital del departamento de Antioquia, entonces su acento es paisa.

En general paisa se refiere al acento que se habla en Antioquia
y en alguna medida el que se habla en los departamentos de Caldas, Quindío y Risaralda, ya que estos tuvieron una gran migración conocida como "la colonización paisa".

"paisa" también se usa como gentilicio alterno a los nacidos en el departamento de Antioquia, cuyo gentilicio es "antioqueño".

Comment: solo he oído ese tal... "piszhina" de la boca de Maluma y no de otras personas paisas (sí buscaba muchas entrevistas en youtube!)... hay alguna explicación?

Comment: Simple y al punto. El muchacho es simplemente **paisa**.  Lo demás es buscarle pelos al calvo. :)
Saludos desde Medallo